How to have different FuncFormatter for different plots using a dynamic variable
I have several figures where I want to show a same curve with right y-axis and with different scales.
The different figures are generated inside a loop, and I would like the scaling to depend directly on a loop variable.
Here is a code working, but the scale factors are fixed.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

data = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (20))

# The following works, right axis of both figures is scaled by 2 and 10, respectively
for right_scale in [2, 10]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
    if right_scale == 2:
        formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:.2f}'.format(x * 2))
    else:
        formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:.3f}'.format(x * 10))
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()

Here is a code not working when having dynamic scale factors. My guess is that the formatter is linked to the variable right_scale and does not just take its value when defining formatter.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

data = np.random.normal(0, 0.01, (20))
# The following does not work, right axis of both figures is scaled by 10
for right_scale in [2, 10]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
    if right_scale == 2:
        formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:.2f}'.format(x * right_scale))
    else:
        formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:.3f}'.format(x * right_scale))
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()

I don't know how to make the second case work.
